# CoreData: Different subclasses from common base entity in different projects

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a generic model framework with a few entities and relationships that I'd like to use for a variety of apps.  For each app, I would like to define a specific set of attributes on one of those entities.  I was thinking each app could define an entity that is the child of the base entity, but it doesn't seem like you can do that if the child is in a different model file.  And if I put all the children entities in the same model file, then the entity in each app will end up with attributes for all the apps.

My only solution at this point is to only have the base entity and have its attribute be a dictionary.  Then each application can write a subclass of NSManagedObject that defines properties which look up the appropriate values in the dictionary.  I think there could be perf issues with this though.

Any other ideas, or thought on my dictionary approach?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I hadn't realized when I posted this was that you can modify the model programmatically.  So I started doing that in each subproject to add the subentity in with the project-specific attributes.  This solved the problem for a while.

However, model migration was an issue.  I thought that if I changed something in the model file in the base project, I'd be able to use automatic migration or mapping files to migrate whatever datastores the subprojects had made.  However, since the subprojects modify the model, I would have had to load up the old model, modify it, load up the new model, modify it, and then perform the migration across those two.

All that would be a pain, so I ended up changing my DB schema to something more flexible, using generic objects, attributes, and values tables.  Now each subproject can just throw in whatever data is wants to define a new kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same questions... I have a base class that defines attributes and functionality common to two CD Entities.  But when I try to access a value from the superclass I get an error.

Here is what I did to solve it.

Make your data model, and generate the classes per usual.  Hand-create the superclass, as a subclass of NSManagedObject.  Give it the same structure as the generated classes, meaning no declared vars, use @dynamic, NSNumber * for numbers, etc.

That did the trick for me.